# Using active sheet instead of using sheet name Public / Private Sub code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the code below without having to write out the sheet name in Sheets("Sheet1").Activate in the Public Sub function, so I can just click on the sheet and run the code. I am unfamiliar with VBA language, and this should be a simple fix, but after an hour of trying things out, I can't get it working so I'm asking here now. Also, when I remove the Sheets("Sheet1").Activate, the abbrev sheet is then activated so the function does not run on that instead of my desired sheet. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Public gcolWords As New Collection

Public Sub ReplaceAllWrds()
Dim vWord, vAbv, itm
Dim i As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Integer

LoadAbbrevs

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("F" & Lastrow).Select
For Each itm In gcolWords
   i = InStr(itm, ":")
   vWord = Left(itm, i - 1)
   vAbv = Mid(itm, i + 1)
   Replace1Wrd vWord, vAbv
Next
Set gcolWords = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Replace1Wrd(ByVal pvWrd, pvAbv)
On Error Resume Next


    Selection.Replace What:=pvWrd, Replacement:=pvAbv, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub

Private Sub LoadAbbrevs()
Dim vWord, vAbv, vItm

Sheets("abbrevs").Activate
Range("A2").Select
While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
   vWord = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
   vAbv = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
   vItm = vWord & ":" & vAbv
   
   gcolWords.Add vItm
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select   'next row
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a `Excel.Worksheet` that points to the `ActiveSheet`, and then use it to keep the reference:

```
Public Sub ReplaceAllWrds()
    Dim vWord, vAbv, itm
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Lastrow As Integer
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    LoadAbbrevs

    ws.Activate
    'MsgBox "The name of the ws sheet is " & ws.Name
    Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F" & Lastrow).Select
    For Each itm In gcolWords
       i = InStr(itm, ":")
       vWord = Left(itm, i - 1)
       vAbv = Mid(itm, i + 1)
       Replace1Wrd vWord, vAbv
    Next
    Set gcolWords = Nothing
End Sub
```

As a note, you could review your code using worksheet objects; this way you can operate directly via Worksheet references, and you don't need to activate the sheets when you operate on them.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to activate the sheet if you're using worksheet objects.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "Example"
```

Using the worksheet objects can speed up your code and you don't need to worry about what sheet is active.

The following is a quick example of what your `LoadAbbrevs` could be.

```
Sub Example()
Dim WS as Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("abbrevs")
Dim RowIndex as Integer
RowIndex = 2
While WS.Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value <> ""
    gcolWords.add WS.Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value + ":" + WS.Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value
    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
Wend
End Sub
```